# Can't get Grunt to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, terminal, gruntjs

**I'm a little confused as to why I can't get my Gruntfile.js to run, here's the rub:**

I installed grunt globally using npm.  It lives in my `/usr/local/bin/` directory, here it is: 
[image]

Previously, I'd installed node.js using homebrew, then grunt with npm. Other issues led me to uninstall node via homebrew & reinstall node directly from the disk image node provides.

In my web project's index, there's a `Gruntfile.js` script that rebuilds my jekyll site everytime live-reload updates. When I run `grunt`, I get this message:
[image]
**What I'm trying to wrap my head around**: 
Why isn't `/usr/local/bin/grunt` a valid path? Grunt *exists* at that location. My guess was that running grunt locally, from within my website's index, would fix things.

There's a `node_modules` folder there & everything was working fine before after all. [I found this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias), and tried running `\grunt` to bypass the bash alias, but that had no effect.

**Any advice/suggestions are much appreciated!** I feel like an imbecile using things, breaking things & not understanding why/how. Eager to finish my project, get a paycheck & finally have time to learn the ins and outs of terminal, bash & popular package managers so I don't run into these sorts of problems...

Comment: Please run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/grunt` to check whether grunt is an executable file, or a soft link. My guess is: `/usr/local/bin/grunt` is a soft symbolic link but point to the wrong place. That's why you can see it under `/usr/local/bin` but cannot execute it.

Comment: Hello again, haha. It's a symbolic link, checked earlier: http://imgur.com/a/UOJAs

Comment: Can you use command line to check where the symbolic link point to?

Comment: Points to `/usr/local/bin`: http://imgur.com/a/UOJAs

Comment: you are using GUI. Please open terminal and run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/grunt`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is the place where symbolic link `grunt` lives, it's not where the symbolic link point to.

Comment: My apologies: http://imgur.com/a/UOJAs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153307/discussion-between-shaochuancs-and-androbaut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with OP, I find this is a Node.js environment issue. After install - do something - uninstall - reinstall in another way - do something, somehow, when `npm install -g XXX` is executed, the symbolic link is created and point to some place, but the package is installed some where else. That's why OP *see* `/usr/local/bin/grunt` but cannot run it.

I've recommended OP to clean up all Node.js stuff, make a clean environment and start right from the beginning.